# How to limit windows height when maximizing?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, desktop-customization, rocketdock

I use Rocket Dock on my win7 ultimate on home computer.

When I maximize windows I want that Rocket Dock should still be visible, exactly like it does in Mac.

So how do I limit height a window can attain when maximised?

Answer (score -1):

u can use MaxMax software....it limits the size of maximizing windows.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.